# Performance of table access

Tags: c++, c, performance, oracle-pro-c

We have an application which is completely written in C. For table access inside the code like fetching some values from a table we use Pro*C. And to increase the performance of the application we also preload some tables for fetching the data. We take some input fields and fetch the output fields from the table in general.

We usually have around 30000 entries in the table and max it reaches 0.1 million some times.

But if the table entries increase to around 10 million entries, I think it dangerously affects the performance of the application.

Am I wrong somewhere? If it really affects the performance, is there any way to keep the performance of the application stable?

What is the possible workaround if the number of rows in the table increases to 10 million considering the way the application works with tables?

Comment: What is the actual question? Your question is really hard to understand. Otherwise, the answer to your question is "there is no way to tell unless you use a profiler" anyway.

Comment: "1 lakh" is 100.000 in Indian English

Comment: You are copying 10 million rows from the database to the application memory? Assuming you need the data for a single row lookup, are you sure your code is faster than Oracle's code. Just always use the SQL statements. Oh ... is performance critical??? If your program takes 0.03 milli seconds using your code and 3 milli seconds (100 times more) using Oracle code who's going to notice?

Comment: The question is then "How to improve search times on a table ranging 30.000 to 10Million elements?"

Comment: @pmg Oracle? SQL? too high level: this is C...

Comment: Why do you cache Oracle table data in your app? Oracle can do it just fine, and in many cases way better that your app. You can configure Oracle to load entire table into memory, if it fits, of course. Let database engine handle the data.

Comment: @jpinto (Olá compatriota): [ http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pro*C ] says "Pro*C ... is an embedded SQL programming language used by Oracle Database ..."

Comment: @jpint3912 Just FYI - Pro*C implies Oracle

Comment: correct embedded star url: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pro%2aC

Answer (score 0):

If you are not sorting the table you'll get a proportional increase of search time... if you don't code anything wrong, in your example (30K vs 1M) you'll get 33X greater search times. I'm assumning you're incrementally iterating (i++ style) the table.

However, if it's somehow possible to sort the table, then you can greatly reduce search times. That is possible because an indexer algorithm that searchs sorted information will not parse every element till it gets to the sought one: it uses auxiliary tables (trees, hashes, etc), usually much faster to search, and then it pinpoints the correct sought element, or at least gets a much closer estimate of where it is in the master table.

Of course, that will come at the expense of having to sort the table, either when you insert or remove elements from it, or when you perform a search.

Comment: totally if all the 10 million entries will be preloaded into memory.it will come aroung loading 7GB of data into memory and i dont think it works

Comment: So it's two different issues: memory and search time. If this is huge data on disk (seams that way, but correct me), you're not gaining anything by loading it to memory (it will get page-filed by the OS). Perhaps you need to build a hash table suitable for faster search (depends on your criteria), with pointers to data on disk?

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can go to 'google hash' and take a look at their implementation? although it is in C++

Answer (score 0):

It might be that you have too many cache misses once you increase over 1MB or whatever your cache size is.

If you iterate table multiple times or you access elements randomly you can also hit lot of cache misses.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_cache#Cache_Misses

Answer (score 0):

Well, it really depends on what you are doing with the data.   If you have to load the whole kit-and-kabootle into memory, then a reasonable approach would be to use a large bulk size, so that the number of oracle round trips that need to occur is small.

If you don't really have the memory resources to allow the whole result set to be loaded into memory, then a large bulk size will still help with the Oracle overhead.   Get a reasonable size chunk of records into memory, process them, then get the next chunk.

Without more information about your actual run time environment, and business goals, that is about as specific as anyone can get.

Can you tell us more about the issue?